# why does compiler choose bool over string_view when given a const char * as the type of the templated argument?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, overload-resolution

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void update(bool const & v)
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << v << std::endl;
    }

    void update(std::string_view v)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
};


template <typename T>
void update(T const & item)
{
    A a;
    a.update(item);
}


int main()
{
    const char * i = "string";
    update(i);
}
```

when I call update with a `const char *`, compiler calls the function with `bool` argument instead of `string_view` ?! why ??!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversion from `const char *` to `std::string_view` (via the [constructor of `std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view)) is a user-defined conversion; which is a worse match than the standard conversion (the [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions) from `const char*` to `bool`) in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences).

> 1) A standard conversion sequence is always better than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence.